# How do you add buttons?

Tags: javascript, button, addition

I'm looking for how to add two buttons under the 'You feel a stick stuck to the wall with something like honey. Next to it is a few rocks.' part. These 2 buttons appear right under the statement. How do I do this? Here's the current code:

```
<script>
function one()
{
    var newButton1 = '<button id="btnTwo" onclick="two()" >Pick up stick</button>'; 
    var newButton2 = '<button id="btnThree"    onclick="three()">Leave it  
there</button>';
    document.getElementById("a").style.width = '330px';
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="<div style='width:220px;float:left'>You feel 
something on the ground, and you think it's a stick.</div>"+newButton1+newButton2;
    var myButton = document.getElementById('btnOne');
    myButton.onclick = four;
}
function two()
{
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for
something.";

document.getElementById("inventory").style.display = "block";

document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
}
function three()
{
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="You leave the stick on the ground and continue  
on.";

document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
}

function four()
{
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="You feel a stick stuck to the wall with  
something like honey. Next to it is a few rocks.";
}
</script>


<div style="margin-left:15px; width:200px; margin-top:100px;">
<button id="btnOne" onclick="one()">Feel around the cave</button>
</div>

<div id="entire" style="margin-left:250px; margin-top:-19px; width:200px; 
height:400px;">
<div id="d"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="a"></div>
</div>

<div style="height:400px;">
<div id="inventory" style="margin-left:550px; width:100px; height:100px; margin-
top:-400px; border: 1px solid #ffffff; display:none;">
<div style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px;">Sticks: 1</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where else have you looked for this information? What have you tried?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using a templating language like Handlebars in addition to jQuery here.

Comment: @LeeAllan - I've tried using something like the var newButton1 code that I used above, and I've tried adding that to both function one and function four.